# Can't use .cs file in a view in already compiled app

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a compiled app and just want to include a class in one of the views and use its methods.

This app is already compiled and I don't have access to its source. I included my class in Views folder, gave it a namespace and then tried to include it by `@using my.namespace.here;` but it's not working.

So how do you include a .cs file in a view?

Comment: When saying 'View' are you referring to a Razor view for an MVC application? Also what do you mean by 'compiled app'? Is it a DLL library that you want to use in your project? Try to add more tags (like aspnet-mvc) because c# is too generic.

Comment: Try creating an assembly `MyAssembly.dll` with your class `MyClass` in it, then in the view use `var myAss = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly"); var myClass = myAss.GetType("MyClass"); dynamic myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myClass);`. Not sure if this would work if views are compiled.

Comment: Only was is if your have the source or the dll was compiled with the source included.   Most compiled dlls don't use the option to include source (debug info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use an external piece of code, in a DLL library. It that's true, you should do the following.

1. Add a reference:
   Expand your project, right click on references, then Add reference. In an opened window click Browse and select DLL you want to use. Now you should see it when you expand References in solution explorer.
2. Add `@using`  in your View.
3. Use the class and methods you want.

Comment: The `using` should be the same as namespace stated in dll file, right?

Comment: Yes. Also this DLL can contain more namespaces, be sure to use the right one